# Negative margin-right is not behaving correctly in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, margin

Hi guys I'm trying to crop an image using another div. Margin -left,-top,-bottom work, but for some reason margin-right does not seem to be working for me on chrome. Any ideas what I should do? I've been trying to figure this out for hours :c

http://knowmad.herokuapp.com/sunapp/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why the margin-right isn't working but did you consider using the clip property?

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-simple-but-useful-css-properties

Answer (score 0):

Use pixels in margin-right instead of percentages. ie `margin-right:20px`